# Jitter in Sticky Header in Safari

Tags: safari

I am trying to get the section headers on this page that read "Celebrity," "Editorial," and "Online" to stick to the top of the left sidebar on scroll:

http://jamiewolf.com/pages/press

They are now sticking properly but jitter in Safari. Would really appreciate any thoughts.